# How to get URL specified in RequestMapping and it's mapping to specific beans in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, request-mapping

I am working on the authentication scheme of a client. The application requires me to get the BeanDefinitions of the controller classes and to get their respective URL mappings. I am using configurableApplicationContext to get the BeanDefinitionNames and then their respective BeanDefinitions but I have no idea how to get the mapped URLs. It would be great if anyone could let me know what to look at.

Thanks.

Comment: I have not understand what you want to do?! Normally you annotate your Method in the @ Controller with @ RequestMapping and when your app-context is annotation-configured it maps the urls on its own

Comment: You can always use reflection to get the annotations if there is no other way.

Comment: I am trying to create an ACL on the basis of URLs and for that I need the mapping of URLs to beans. The controllers are already annotated with RequestMapping. I need to access these Mappings on initialisation to create a list of routes the user has access to.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to use spring-security for that. There you can implement a url based ACL

Comment: I would but due to some constraints, I can't.